# mini pc as dev server - specs?

Tags: linux, pc, development, power, web-development

I want a new **no-noise** dev server (LEMP); and **I wonder what specs I should go for**, how to narrow the search.

I currently use an old budget Laptop (Asus K53U) with an AMD C-50@800MHz, 1x2GB Samsung DDR3-1333 and the HDD replaced by a Samsung 830 (250GB SSD , SATA 3.0, 6GB/s), which is sufficient for the most part; but the fan has grown (kind of) noisy and on occasions I´d like MySQL to work a bit faster.

The hardest work that the machine has to do are the web tests. According to `top`, MySQL constantly uses 30% of the RAM, and, whenever it has something to do, it maxes out one core of the CPU, while the other one is idling, which is both not surprising: The CPU scores 66 at Cinebench R20 (single core), and MySQL uses only one core per connection.

I definitely can´t get anything slower nowadays; but how high must I aim?

I thought about something in the (physical) dimensions of a Mac Mini or smaller, maybe a NUC, with a **35W power** supply, housing a **Core i3**, any **250GB NVMe or SSD** and take whatever comes with it. No special needs on the connecting side; I think it should have video output of some kind. Passive cooling is a must.

SMART claims that the 830 is still in good shape; so I will probably use that as 1st level backup.

---

Hints on the specification will suffice at the moment;
but if you have a similar scenario; let me know what you use.

- Should I downgrade to a mobile processor for lower power consumption? upgrade to i5 for better performance? or stick with the i3?
- I think about moving from Ubuntu to Puppy or TinyCore. Anything to consider on the driver side?
- Anything else I haven´t thought about?

Comment: That missing RAM is probably allocated to the iGPU. On a DIY PC you would be able to change the amount, but on a laptop I'm not sure.

Comment: I used my MacMini for the time being. It´s too old for the latest Mac OS anyway, has an i3 and no fan. Now that I don´t have a fan in my office anymore, I hear that HDD hum. Some day I´m gonna ditch it and replace it with an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

The System76 Tall Meerkat checks most of the boxes, except the fan:

- 10th gen Intel Core i3
- up to 2*32GB of RAM (max 2666mhz because of intel cpu)
- WIFI can be turned off
- ships with Ubuntu or POP OS
- small size
- its not fanless, but has a quiet mode in the bios. But its pretty hard to do passive cooling on a small pc

Comment: Thanks for the hint; but it seems I can´t get it in Europe; customs and taxes would push the price to ~800€, plus the potential trouble. Makes no sense when I can get a Mac Mini for less than 600.

Comment: True, but the Mac Mini has a MacOS lockdown, and thats why I don't like it. Installing another OS would be as hard as installing a different OS on some android phones.

Comment: IC. But still, I can order a Cirrus7, which is fanless, for ~700€. The thing is, I´m not sure about the power that I need for what I want.

Comment: Yes, thats doable, but the Intel T processors mean you are very limited on power, so your clock speeds and overall speeds will be low.

Comment: Check out the [silentmaxx Kenko mini](https://www.silentmaxx.de/lautlose-PC/Office-Home/KENKO-Mini.html)

Comment: btw: I went for the Cirrus 7 Nimbus with a Celeron G6900T@2800MHz, 2x8GB DDR4 @3200MHz, 970 EvoPlus 500GB). The only problem I keep bumping in is that I forget to power it down. =D And the RAM boost improved MySQL performance a lot!